# Update mutiple rows from dynamically generated input field PHP, MySQL,jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, input

I need some advice on how to successfully update mutiple rows in my database from dynamically created input fields. 
So, what I have is this:

**PHP**

```
<?php
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       echo "<input class='estemated_days' type='text' id='".$row['scpe_id']."' value='".$row['scpe_estemated_days']."'></td>";
   }
?>
```

This will output something like this:
**HTML**

```
<input class='estemated_days' type='text' id='718' value='5'>
<input class='estemated_days' type='text' id='719' value='8'>
<input class='estemated_days' type='text' id='720' value='10'>

<input type='button' id='save' value='Save'> <!-- Button to jQuery -->
```

.....etc.

Here is where my knowledge is lacking. I want jQuery to do something like this:
**jQuery**

```
($"#save").click(function () {

  // Get value of id from (".estemated_days") as an identifier, and get the input value it contains
  // Send to /update.php

});
```

Then, the `update.php` would do something like this:
 **PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

    /*
        Get all of the id's and the value it contain's

        perform:
    */

    mysql_query = ("UPDATE myDatabase SET estemated_days = '$the_value_from_the_input' WHERE scpe_id = '$the_value_of_the_id'");
    //Repeat this for all rows from the webpage
}

?>
```

My knowledge is basic web programming but I would really like to make this work. Anyone got advice on how I should do it?

Comment: [<input>](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input) tags don't have a `data-id` attribute. Why not use `id`?

Comment: @Mike oh, i did not know that. Yeah, I guess ID would work. I'll edit this in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var values = {};
$('input.estimated_days').each(function(n, el){
   values[ $(el).attr('id') ] = $(el).val();
});

$.ajax(
  {
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'update.php',
    data : {edays: values}
  }
); /// see jquery docs for ajax callbacks 

<?php
   foreach($_POST['edays'] as $id=>$value) // ...
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
also
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

... and don't forget to sanitize the input for mysql

Comment: Thank's! I will try this out asap.

Comment: thank you. Do you have any idea on why this code wont update my database? See pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/p8ks686W I noticed now I didn't end with a semicolon but this is added now and still no luck.

Comment: Define yourself a success callback in jquery ajax that alerts you to the output: `success : function(data){ alert(data); }` - you can then var_dump $_POST or dump mysql last error and get that output in a popup. See the jquery ajax link to learn about callbacks